# Element of array set as integer instead of float

Tags: python, numpy

I have issues setting an element of an array to a float number.

```
C = [(np.random.randint(-10,10),np.random.randint(-10,10)) for i in range(3)]
C = np.array(C)
C[0,0] = 1.654
print(C[0,0])
```

> 1

I wonder why this is not 1.654 but gives me the integer 1 instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have the solution....
I have to use the numpy array dtype parameter which says:

> dtype : data-type, optional The desired data-type for the array. If
>   not given, then the type will be determined as the minimum type
>   required to hold the objects in the sequence. This argument can only
>   be used to ‘upcast’ the array. For downcasting, use the .astype(t)
>   method.

```
C = [(np.random.randint(-10,10),np.random.randint(-10,10)) for i in range(3)]
C = np.array(C,dtype='float32')
C[0,0] = 1.654
print(C[0,0])
```

So clearly, C is of dtype int because this is sufficient to store the random integer values. If I now want to set an element of C to a float value I have to change the dtype of C.

Answer (score 1):

Because you use `randint` which is giving a integer value.
Change the code to this for getting the float.

```
import numpy as np

C = [(float(np.random.randint(-10,10)),float(np.random.randint(-10,10))) for i in range(3)]
C = np.array(C)
C[0,0] = 1.654
print(C[0,0])
```